# Spring Batch - Transactional REQUIRES_NEW during processor step

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-transactions

i have an issue with using @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) during the processor step in the batch chunk processing.

What I try to achieve is to persist custom data during the processor step:

```
public class AbstractImportRecordProcessor implements InitializingBean, ImportContextAware,
    ItemProcessor<ImportRecord, BatchReportBasket> {

@Autowired
private TransactionBasketService transactionBasketService;

@Override
public final BatchReportBasket process(final ImportRecord item) {

...
transactionBasketService.save(transactionBasket);
...
}
}
```

And the service impl:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void save(final TransactionBasket transactionBasket) {
}
```

If i don't add the @Transactional, the data is not persisted on exceptions because of the rollback.

If I use the @Transactional the exception handling of the base processing seems to be broken. If an exception occurs then, it will be not processed as before.

So somehow, the @Transactional has an effect on the chunk transaction processing and the exception handling. From my point of view, this should not happen.

Any ideas why this happens?

---

EDIT: more info on why we need this

We process import records and send them to the writer. In our process we get 90 % the same "data" every day. Therefore, we need to save which data we already processed during the last run. If we know in the processor that we already processed the data, we can just skip it and do not send it to the writer. in order to do this, we want to save the primary key of the data into a dedicated database table. This information should be persistent regardless of any exceptions in the writer.

If we would put that into a listener, we are already done with the processing and could not do such a thing.

---

Thanks in advance for your input.

Comment: You shouldn't be saving in a processor, that is the tasks of the `ItemWriter`.

Comment: OK, but we need to save some kind of "Audit" entries and we need the info of the processor. Nevertheless, do you know why this happens not to work in detail?

Comment: because you shouldn't be saving in a processor. Saving is tied to the chunk processing. What audit information do you need/want to store? Generally a better place is to use a chunk listener for that.

Comment: i added some info why we need this into the question above

Comment: Which is a perfect use case for a skiplistener.

Comment: OK, thanks. Then we will do it in a listener. But nevertheless i would be interessted why exactly the REQUIRES_NEW in a processor does not work. Do you know the details?